# Using Ivy as dependency resolver in Grails

Tags: grails, dependencies, ivy, dependency-resolver

I'm having a few problems while trying to use ivy as dependency resolver.

I have the following line in my BuildConfig:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "ivy"
```

And SpringFramework and JUnit dependencies were not being resolved at all.

I had to manually put it under dependencies.

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.0.6.RELEASE'
compile 'junit:junit:4.11'
```

But it doesn't seem right to me. I was getting a NoClassDefFound error on compile stage without the springframework dependency and could not run my app without junit dependency.

Any ideas on how to solve this without putting these dependencies?

Comment: Do you having only compile time errors? Did you get some pre-compile errors (something like "download impossible" or "ivy is absent")?

Comment: And what is your Grails version?